# Azure AD user objects - Clear off immutable ID

Tags: entra-id

Is there a way to clear off immutable ID from user object synced from local AD?

I tried this:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName userid@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com | Set-MsolUser -ImmutableId "$null"
```

But it returns this error:

> Set-MsolUser : Unable to update parameter. Parameter name: IMMUTABLEID.
>   At line:1 char:65
>   + Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName userid@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com | Set-MsolUser -Im ...
>   +                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PropertyNotSettableException,Microsoft.Online
>      .Administration.Automation.SetUser

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Shobhit Vaish

Comment: You get this error message is because property is not settable thus you get PropertyNotSetableException. Why you want to clear this ID? It ties the objects in On-premise with that in Cloud.

Comment: I know I did not give an answer, but to clear the immutableID is really not a safe behavior. Any update from you?